# return a real instance in a function which has a T in three conditions?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I create a function that will get data from the url and then **DeserializeAsync** to T object.

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url,string param)
{
    var response= await httpClient.GetAsync(url,new HttpContent(param));
    
    if(response is null)
    {
      //I want to return T.
    }
    if(!response.Content is null)
    {
        //return new T();
    }
    var str=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(str);
}
```

what I want to do is:

1. If the response is null then return `new T();`
2. If the response is not null but the r`esponse.StatusCode` is `NoContent` then return `new T()` which  `T.IsSuccess = true;`
3. otherwise return DeserializeAsync();

but I do not know what class is T and T maybe not have property of `IsSuccess`.

Comment: To be able to do `new T();` `T` has to be constraint to having a paramterless constructor so add the `where T: new()` constraint. This requires `T` to have a public paramterless constructor ensuring `new T();` is a valid call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can accomplish without limiting your options for `T` is to use a wrapper class. Think of something like this:

```cs
public class ResponseWrapper<T>
{
    public T Data { get; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; }

    public ResponseWrapper<T>() : this (false) { }

    public ResponseWrapper<T>(bool isSuccess)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
    }

    public ResponseWrapper<T>(T data) : this(true) 
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```cs
public async Task<ResponseWrapper<T>> PostAsync<T>(string url,string param)
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url,new HttpContent(param));
    
    if (response is null)
    {
        return new ResponseWrapper<T>();
    }

    if (!response.Content is null)
    {
        return new ResponseWrapper<T>(true);
    }

    var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(str);

    return new ResponseWrapper<T>(data);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Camilo Terevinto.  and what is your advice to do it ?use this wrapper or just return the response? I want make one post function that other can use not have to write the if else sentences.

Comment: @liang.good Well, that's up to you. The pattern I shared here is a very common one. This is the only way you can prevent restricting `T`, however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify type constraints for type T in order to 1) create empte result object and 2) set IsSuccess to true.

```
public interface IPostResult {
    bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

// type T has public parameterless constructor, and supports IPostResult interface (has IsSuccess property)
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url,string param) where T: IPostResult, new()
{
    var response= await httpClient.GetAsync(url,new HttpContent(param));
    
    if(response is null)
    {
        return new T();
    }
    if(!response.Content is null)
    {
        var r = new T();
        r.IsSuccess = true;
        return r;
    }

    var str=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(str);
}
```

Comment: If successful get str to T then T has IsSuccess Property?

Comment: Yes, T declared as supports IPostResult interface so you can assign its IsSuccess property inside PostAsync<T>

Comment: Have you tried? will it run correctly? there is an error while I run it